# Django. form.errors is not visible in template although the form is bound

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm submitting a form with invalid data: string that contain's less then 5 characters (see forms.py), I see that the form is bound, I print form.errors from the view to see the actual errors, I pass form to the template but form.errors is empty in template!

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "VALID"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:success'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = OptionForm()
    print form.is_bound # --> True
    print form.errors # --> errors, see below
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': OptionForm})
```

printed form.errors contains:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>opt<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value has at least 5 characters (it has 3).</li></ul></li></ul>
```

forms.py

```
class OptionForm(forms.Form):
    opt = forms.CharField(min_length=5)
```

index.html

```
<!-- form errors -->
{{ form.errors }}
<form id="option-set" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.opt }}

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

However, if I pass form.error salong with the form object, I will be able to see them.

```
return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': OptionForm, 'errors': form.errors})
```

As I know, errors, or other attributes, should be accessible directly in the template.

I can't see where is the bug! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the form class, OptionForm, rather than the instantiated variable `form`, to the template.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks. now thats a fail. I can accept your answer    in 10minutes.